# Two Approaching Coulomb Charges

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Consider the function

$$y(x)=30-\frac{1}{|x|}-\frac{1}{|x-3|},\;\;\; 0<x<3$$

This is effectively the potential of two Coulomb charges, one at $x=0$ and the other at $x=3$, offset by a constant. If you plot this function, it will have an enclosed area under the curve bounded by the $x$-axis. My question is: how does this area scale with separation of the Coulomb charges?

In more general terms, I am looking for the solution for a general set-up:

$$\int_{x_1}^{x_2} \left( A - \frac{1}{|x-a|}-\frac{1}{|x-b|} \right) \mathrm{d}x$$

where $A>0,a,b$ are constants, and $x_1$, $x_2$ are the appropriate roots at $y=0$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you have $0<x<3$ then you can remove the absolute values, you will easily find the values of $x_1$ and $x_2$ and it will be easier to find the value of the integral.

Comment: Thank you for the advice - this simplifies things a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume $a < x_1 < x_2 < b$, so for $x$ in this interval your integrand is 
$$ f(x) = A - \frac{1}{x-a} + \frac{1}{x-b}$$
Then $f(x) = 0$ for 
$$ x = \frac{a+b}{2} \pm \frac{\sqrt{(a-b)(a-b+4/A)}}{2} $$
where $x_1$ is the value with $-$ and $x_2$ the value with $+$.
The integral is
$$\int_{x_1}^{x_2} f(x)\; dx = A(x_2 - x_1) + \ln\left(\frac{b-x_2}{b-x_1}\right) + \ln\left(\frac{x_1-a}{x_2-a}\right) $$

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply - this is indeed the function of separation ($b-a$) that I was looking for.

Comment: Correction to my comment: the final answer is a function of both $(b-a)$ and $(b+a)$. (As well as $A$, of course.)